# Splitting functionality across controllers that must interact

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are using Angularjs and ui-router.  We generally have a layout of each page that utilizes views.  We have a filter view, sort view, and pagination view; as well as display views that can be swapped in and out.

Logically when changes are made we need to any of theses controllers we need to update the displayData as appropriate.  Changes to filter should run the filterMethod, but also need to run sort and then pagination logic afterwards, while changes to sort should run just pagination after, making a clear order of operations for when each controller needs to it's update.

My problem comes when I consider that in some cases we may not want to utilize all 3 controllers.  We may want filtering, but not pagination for example.

We are having trouble finding a clean way to make these controllers 'just work', so that we can plug in whichever control we want in uirouter and have them function.  The problem is mostly one of scoping.  If I do the obvious thing, and have each controller define their own updateData method when changes are made to it, I run into scoping problems if I want them call the next controller's update afterwords.  The filter controller can't call sort because the two controllers don't share a scope.  I can use broadcasts, but what if I want a filter and a pagination controller, but not a sort?  How do I ensure that sort runs before pagination if both are present, but if sort controller doesn't exist pagination knows to run after filter?

I could instead move everything up to my top level controller, and then things just work.  However then I end up with a controller that feels like it's doing way to much, It's cleaner to have one controller for each type of control if possible.

We have other approaches we could use, but they feel like their making pretty strong presumptions about our controller scheme.  If I later added some fourth controller I would have to modify everything because each controller is really hard coded very explicitly with presumptions about how the other's run.

This seems like a common issue.  Is there a a best practice or convenient technology for handling splitting of functionality across controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Hoist the data, not the display logic. There are only two ways to share data between controllers cleanly: a service, and a parent controller.

If what you were sharing was data (eg: `displayData`), I might suggest a service object, but sounds more like application state (eg: `orderBy`), so I think these "settings" should live on a parent controller.

Comment: I actually have a service for saving the state of the settings, needed because we want that state to persist across pages.  However, what about the logic for controlling the controls (toggling on and off filters etc) and running the updateData method?  If I put that all in one controller wont that get to be quite extensive?  Isn't having so much logic in a single class a code-smell?

Comment: The toggle logic lives as close as possible to the area in question, ie: the sub-view. It uses the service, or the parent scope, to pass up information. `updateData` is the code smell.